# Appending multiple scores to one entry in a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a textfile and it looks like this :

```
zor:10
zor:21
bob:30
qwerty:46
```

I want it to look like `{'zor': [10, 21,], 'bob': [30]}`  etc but the numbers keep getting replaced when I add multiple scores to a name I split the scores so that the names and scores are in separate positions.

```
elif schClass == '2':
     schClass = open("scores2.txt", 'r')
     li = open("scores2.txt", 'r')
     data = li.read().splitlines()
     for li in data:
        name = li.split(":")[0]
        score = li.split(":")[1]
        if name not in diction1:
            diction1[name] = score
        elif name in diction1  :
            diction1[name] = diction1[name + int(score)]
            print(diction1)
```

Comment: Look into [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: Looks like simple typo: `diction1[name] = diction1[name + int(score)]` should be `diction1[name] = diction1[name] + int(score)` But aren't you getting a `KeyError` this way?

Comment: yes I am and none of them seem to work?

Comment: @andreapirlo You don't need the `elif name in diction1:` statement, just `else:` would do, but see @Martijn Pieters answer which solves lots more problems you have.

Comment: Please don't change your original question; your question is supposed to be useful for future visitors too. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are not building lists; simply use the [`dict.setdefault()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to insert a list object when the key is missing, and append your values:

```
diction1 = {}
with open("scores2.txt", 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        name, _, score = line.partition(':')
        diction1.setdefault(name, []).append(int(score))
```

I took the liberty to clean up your code a little; I'm using the file as a context manager so that it is closed again automatically. By looping directly over the file you get individual lines, no need to split first. And I used [`str.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to split just the once (it is more efficient for that case than `str.split()` is).

Demo:

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> sample = '''\
... zor:10
... zor:21
... bob:30
... qwerty:46
... '''
>>> diction1 = {}
>>> with StringIO(sample) as infile:
...     for line in infile:
...         name, _, score = line.partition(':')
...         diction1.setdefault(name, []).append(int(score))
... 
>>> diction1
{'bob': [30], 'qwerty': [46], 'zor': [10, 21]}
```

Comment: why does it say open twice?

Comment: @andreapirlo: because [I made a typo](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21215266#21215266) that has since been corrected.

Comment: @andreapirlo: define *doesn't work* here? Perhaps you made a typo?

Comment: no I never the scores don't get printed out I added print(diction1) but the textfile does not print at alll

Comment: @andreapirlo: so what *is* printed? Perhaps you need to add some more print statements to see what code is executed and what isn't?

Comment: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @andreapirlo: do you already have **other** values in that dictionary? If you already have a dictionary with `{'zor': 'some string'}` then the code will indeed raise that exception as you cannot append to an existing string value; it's not a list.

Comment: @andreapirlo: that's a *very important detail*. What did you expect to happen in that case? Can you please update your question to include that information and what you expect to happen with those existing values?